# Error in tag$name : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors , when reading text files in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to do some text analytics in Shiny. First I upload some text file through the fileinput() option in the ui.R file. The relevant snippet of the Ui.R is as shown below ( FileInput)

Ui.R file

```
sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("langsel","Choose Your Language:",choices=list("English"="eng","Hindi"="hind")), # This will go as drop down in the app. 

      br(), # A break in the panel

      uiOutput("movie_list"), # This list of movies will  come from renderUI of server based on selection of language

      br(),

      fileInput("movtext","Upload the movie reviews"), # The fileinput() function is used to get the fileupload option

      helpText("Default File Size is 5 MB") # A help text 





        ), # End of sidebarpanel
```

After the text document is uploaded through the ui.R, I read it through a reactive function in the "server.r" file. The file is being read properly and is displayed properly. The below is the snippet of the "server.R" file.

server.r

```
textanalysis <- reactive({


                                  text1 <- input$movtext # Stores the uploaded file in the variable text1. The uploaded file is a text file 
                                  movtxt1 <- scan(text1$datapath,character(0),sep=".") # Reading the text file using the "scan" function
```

However, when I try to find the length of the text strings using the length() function. It throws the error as

> Error in tag$name : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

I know there are multiple strings in the "movtxt1" variable because when I subset it with movtxt1[1] or any other value it shows the relevant text. I am trying to find the number of strings that are there as part of this text file, which I am unable to with the length() function. Request your help to solve the same.

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you have a reproducible example.

Comment: Please also provide the rest of your code. I need to know in which context your reactive expression is called.